# Mapping page tables with pte_map_offset

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am doing some linux kernel work, and I am iterating over the page tables simultaneously of three different page directories. When I got down to needing to map the page tables, I used `pte_offset_map`. However, I realized that with high memory enabled, this method will not work since `pte_offset_map` will try to use the same kmap slot (pte_offset_map uses `kmap_atomic` in linux 2.6.32). I see that there is a `pte_offset_map_nested` that uses the other `kmap_atomic` slot.

However, I need to map three different page tables at once. I've thought of some solutions to only have to map two page tables at once (I could interleave back and forth and only map two at the same time , or copy one page table temporarily while I map the other two, etc...) but those solutions are undesirable. I though about mapping the third page table manually with `kmap_atomic(pmd_page(*pmd), KM_USER0)`, but this approach does not seem very general across different kernel versions. However, I do believe this approach is the best in terms of efficiency and simplicity.

Are there any thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vmalloc`'s address space for mapping arbitrary pages. See these APIs:

```
extern void vm_unmap_ram(const void *mem, unsigned int count);
extern void *vm_map_ram(struct page **pages, unsigned int count,
                        int node, pgprot_t prot);
```